# posting to friends wall using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can I post to a friends wall using the facebook javascript SDK?

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @ifaour's answer on `FB.api`...

- Set oauth and status parameters in `FB.init`
- Request extended permission, publish_stream, via `FB.login`

**Other resources:**

[using facebook stream publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846942/using-facebook-stream-publish)

**Complete example...**

```html
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'APP_ID',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true , // parse XFBML
        oauth : true // Enable oauth authentication
    });

    FB.login(function(response)
    {
        if (response.authResponse)
        {
            alert('Logged in!');

            // Post message to friend's wall

            var opts = {
                message : 'Post message',
                name : '',
                link : 'http://www....',
                description : 'Description here',
                picture : 'http://domain.com/pic.jpg'
            };

            FB.api('/FRIEND_ID/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
            {
                if (!response || response.error)
                {
                    alert('Posting error occured');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Not logged in');
        }
    }, { scope : 'publish_stream' });
};

</script>

<!-- FACEBOOK -->        
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  // replacing with an older version until FB fixes the cancel-login bug
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  //e.src = 'scripts/all.js';
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<!-- END-OF-FACEBOOK -->
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [`FB.api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) method, something like:

```js
var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/FRIEND_ID/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: hey I tried this and I got a POST http://myipaddress/Discover/FacebookItemRecommend 404 (Not Found), why is this

Comment: @aherlambang: Well, without seeing your code I won't be able to answer you. How about asking a new question with your code and the error you are getting

Comment: File:   https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
Line No:  85
Error Detail: Error: Domain contained invalid characters.