# Posting a facebook status update from a website

Tags: facebook

I have a website where after a conversion process the client wants the user to be able to share this on Facebook and Twitter etc.

The concept I have seen before, where I have a Facebook panel in my page which posts directly to their Facebook - much like the Twitter share:

[image]

Question is, given that I can't find anything like this on the web, is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [this](http://nocturnsoft.com/devblog/?p=1745) or [this](http://bobbelderbos.com/2011/08/example-facebook-php-sdk-post-to-friends-wall/) . You can use Javascript to do so as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845837/posting-to-friends-wall-using-facebook-javascript-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

What you see here are comments ([Facebook comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)). In this particular screenshort you are logged in and no one has already commented.

But you also may want to take a look at the [send button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/).

Answer (score 0):

I havn't looked at this too much in the past, but it's possible that there's some functionality for this sort of stuff in the facebook API, whether or not this supports what you're looking for i'm not entirely sure. Heres a few links that might be of use to you:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/ - this may be of use to use a plugin